# I want to import the values from user, for this t test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I dont want a,b to be random, i want them to be specific, so user will input the 2 samples, so it can count according to it(variance, mean, size)
I tried it this way:

```
size = input('Size of sample: ')
N = size

source2 = input('Mean: ')
source3 = input('Distribution: ')
a = source2 
print("a:",a)
```

Gauss-eloszlású adat, átlag = 0 és variancia = 1

```
b = source3
print("b:",b)
```

Import the packages

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
```

Define 2 random distributions
Sample Size

```
N = 10
```

Gaussian distributed data with mean = 2 and var = 1

```
a = np.random.randn(N) + 2
```

Gaussian distributed data with with mean = 0 and var = 1

```
b = np.random.randn(N)
```

Calculate the Standard Deviation
Calculate the variance to get the standard deviation

For unbiased max likelihood estimate we have to divide the var by N-1, and therefore the parameter ddof = 1

```
var_a = a.var(ddof=1)
var_b = b.var(ddof=1)
```

std deviation

```
s = np.sqrt((var_a + var_b)/2)
s
```

Calculate the t-statistics

```
t = (a.mean() - b.mean())/(s*np.sqrt(2/N))
```

Compare with the critical t-value
Degrees of freedom

```
df = 2*N - 2
```

p-value after comparison with the t

```
p = 1 - stats.t.cdf(t,df=df)


print("t = " + str(t))
print("p = " + str(2*p))
```

Note that we multiply the p value by 2 because its a twp tail t-test
You can see that after comparing the t statistic with the critical t value (computed internally) we get a good p value of 0.0005 and thus we reject the null hypothesis and thus it proves that the mean of the two distributions are different and statistically significant.

Cross Checking with the internal scipy function

```
t2, p2 = stats.ttest_ind(a,b)
print("t = " + str(t2))
print("p = " + str(2*p2))
```

Comment: fix first your formatting please

Comment: `a` and `b` are just string objects, so they cannot be used like a NumPy array and don't have the `.var()` method. Did you forget to load some data files based on the input provided by the user?